# Ban on Religion

Tags: magic, medieval, religion

How would the population of a large medieval country react to a sudden ban to a certain widespread religion.

Several information regarding the setting:

Gods have real impact on the world. They can flatten mountains and raise islands when they will it.

Nobody denies the existence of the worshipped gods. People are simply banned from worshipping the gods.

Gods gain power through worshippers but this knowledge is only known by the ruler class.

Gods cannot act directly against countries who have their own worshipped god as the other god protects them.

The alignment of the banned religion is true neutral and it's domain is secret knowledge.

The alignment of the official god of the country is lawful good and it's domain is Purity.

At least ten percent of the population officially worships the god of secret knowledge but they are the majority only in distant areas and they are generally compromised of lower class.

Clerics of the religion can channel the divine power of their patron and it is not considered to be a direct interference.

Comment: See the history of England in the 16th century, when alternately Protestantism and Catholicism were banned, or at least heavily restricted. And of course the Thirty Years War.

Comment: If those gods can flatten mountains and raise islands, then they seem fully capable to action directly (and immediately) against any rulers considering a ban --and their families, and their supporters-- well before such ban is announced.

Comment: The gods cannot directly intervene because then other gods would intervene too.

Comment: Hussites! Crusades on people who wanted to drink wine during the ceremony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, people do not really care that much about religion. What they mostly care about is belonging to the social group they identify with. Usually this means people will follow the same religion their family or relatives do or switch to whatever a charismatic leader or group they idolize and want to follow does. Real religious awakening is very rare.

Which is probably a good thing as it probably requires a great need. So it being common would imply things are going **very** badly.

In case of a ban, the religious leaders of the banned religion are removed by the state and replaced by priests of the preferred religion. Attendance in the new services is mandated or at least strongly expected. In case of known followers of the banned religion it would probably be mandatory in practice as they'd need to prove their conversion.

In effect the new religion simply slots in the place of the old one. It takes over the places of worship and holy places. It takes over the congregations and assimilates them into its own. It even takes over the stories and legends, re-framing them in terms of its own theology and mythology.

Note that while people are usually happy to switch their religion, the new religion is generally just as good as the old one and does not involve getting executed or tortured, old habits, ritual and vocabulary are more persistent. Old religious rituals live on as folk rituals and folk magic. Names of old gods live on as swear words or placatory prayers before doing something risky.

Note that all this very much depends on **how** the state implements the ban. I am assuming the state uses similar methods to what have been successfully used in the past in converting nations or areas to Christianity (or Islam). But it is entirely possible to mess this up and actually make the banned religion more resistant to conversion or even more popular than before.

The bottom line really is that inherently banning a religion does very little, it all follows from how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

**What if the god did something really, really bad? And the leaders don't want he/she/it to exist anymore?**

Bear with me here.

Let's assume, for a moment, that a god's existence/power/etc is based purely on their followers, as it does in many settings. Not sure if that's the case with your setting, so this may be completely invalid. With that in mind, I'll dive right in.

This god did something terrible. Like, nearly world ending. Maybe was stopped by some hero or something. Since the god is neutral, perhaps they did it by accident. Or they killed a previous leader, again, since they're neutral, maybe by accident. That's up to you to decide.

Then, whoever is now in power decides this god has to pay. Maybe they're jealous of the god's power to destroy. Maybe they just don't like people dying. Who knows.

So they mandate that worship of this god is illegal. People all over the country stop worshiping this god. Pretty soon, he/she/it ceases to exist.

Or, at least, that's what he/she/it's followers want you to think.

10% of the population (that would be kind of high in this situation, but would still work) pretends to worship the god of purity, but secretly worships the god of secret knowledge, waiting for a time when he/she/it will rise again in glory, and will again be the dominant god!